# Rails + Strongbox: TypeError: can't cast Strongbox::Lock to binary

Tags: ruby-on-rails, console

When I try to create a new recording in console I get this error:

```
TypeError: can't cast Strongbox::Lock to binary
```

However, the other tables where I'm using Strongbox work fine. 
My schema looks like this:

```
create_table "recordings", force: true do |t|
t.datetime "date"
t.string   "position"
t.datetime "created_at"
t.datetime "updated_at"
t.integer  "patient_id"
t.binary   "sound_file"
t.binary   "sound_file_key"
t.binary   "sound_file_iv"
t.binary   "image_file"
t.binary   "image_file_key"
t.binary   "image_file_iv"
t.binary   "audio_data_points"
t.binary   "audio_data_points_key"
t.binary   "audio_data_points_iv"
end

create_table "notes", force: true do |t|
t.integer "user_id"
t.integer "recording_id"
t.integer "patient_id"
t.binary  "content"
t.binary  "content_key"
t.binary  "content_iv"
end
```

My models look like this:

```
class Note < ActiveRecord::Base

  validates :content, presence: true

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :recording
  belongs_to :patient
  encrypt_with_public_key :content,
    :key_pair => Rails.root.join('config','keypair.pem')
end

class Recording < ActiveRecord::Base

  validates :date       , presence: true
  validates :position   , presence: true
  validates :sound_file , presence: true , uniqueness: true
  validates :image_file , presence: true , uniqueness: true

  has_many :notes, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :srecordings
  has_many :users, through: :srecordings
  belongs_to :patient

  encrypt_with_public_key :sound_file, :image_file, :audio_data_points,
    :key_pair => Rails.root.join('config','keypair.pem')
  end
```

I've never used Strongbox before but it's working fine everywhere else, so I don't quite get this one. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Validations for uniqueness does not working well with strongbox. Your recordings model is the only model which is checking for uniqueness of sound_file and image_file. The best possible thing for you would be to add custom validation to check for uniqueness here. Surprisingly I figured this out with very same model :)

P.S. I am implementing the custom validation myself right now for uniqueness.